# RecyclerView within fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

The following RecyclerView crashes when run in a fragment class inside the "else". I get following exeption:

```
01-05 18:19:14.922 18178-18178/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.ymoshel.moshel.handcuffed, PID: 18178
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.designdemo.uaha.ThreeFragments.onCreateView(ThreeFragments.java:153)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1965)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1078)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1259)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1624)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:251)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");
    Log.d(TAG,"strtext: " + strtext);
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_prod_list, container, false);
    mActivity = getActivity();
    thisFragType = getArguments().getInt(ARG_FRAG_TYPE, 0);
    thisFragTypew = getArguments().getInt(ARG_FRAG_TYPE, 1);



    Log.d(TAG, "The Frag Type is: " + thisFragType);
    Log.d(TAG,"test text "+text);
    if (thisFragType==RECENT_ARREST_FRAG||thisFragType==SEARCH_BY_NAME_FRAG) {
        setupRecyclerView(rv);
        return rv;
    }else {
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rssitem_detail,
                container, false);

        arrayListCountyNames = new ArrayList<>();
        test = getArguments().getString("edttext", "default");
        Log.d(TAG, "test: " + test);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emptyView);
        textView.setText(test);


        final String shared_size = getDefaults("shared_size", mActivity);
        Log.d(TAG,"shared_size: "+shared_size);
        String [] listCountys = new String[Integer.parseInt(shared_size)];
        for (int i  = 0 ;i<Integer.parseInt(shared_size);i++){
            final String defaults = getDefaults("shared" + i, mActivity);
            listCountys[i]=defaults;
            arrayListCountyNames.add(defaults);
            Log.d(TAG,"shared: "+defaults);
        }
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        startAdapter(listCountys,listCountys,test );
        // Setup layout manager for items
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity);
        // Control orientation of the items
        // also supports LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        // Attach layout manager to the RecyclerView
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        adapter = new MyPickCountFavoriteArrestAdapter(mActivity,listCountys,listCountys,test);

        return view;
    }
```

This RecyclerView when I run it on a regular activity it works fine, this fragment class is causing the trouble any suggestions?

Comment: Double check the id's in your layout xml please.

Comment: You are right the recyclerview id was wrong, its still not displaying the recyclerview but thats already a different question.

Comment: You need to explicitly set a layout manager on your RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that other views such as "textView" are being found appropriately and not causing a NPE. Something to check here would be if the id "R.id.recyclerview" is actually being found and returning an appropriate value now that you are in the fragment, it is very possible that the recycler view you are trying to find was only present in the layout for the activity and you may need to create one in the fragment too (or only have one in the fragment, since that is what you are already displaying on your activity). Also, the default orientation is already vertical so you do not have to set it as such in code.

Comment: You are right the recyclerview id was wrong, would you know why I am still getting the error: 01-05 19:07:33.496 22597-22597/? E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: You are almost there :). What is missing is that you did create the adapter, but now you need to call recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter). Currently the recyclerview does not detect an adapter telling it how to behave or populate so it does not render.